# Zero distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, differential

A distribution, by the definition given in  Shearer and Levy, is a function $f \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ with $f: C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})=D(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

1. $f$ is linear
2. $f$ is continuous.

A distribution is zero iff $f(\phi)=(f,\phi)=0, \ \  \forall \phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$.
Given $c \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $cf$ is defined in the image below [orange], find all values of $f$ for which $c=e^x$ satisifies $cf=0$.

Attempt:
I have tried to use the example [pink] below (also pictured) but I didn't get very far because I can't find a general function that differentiates to $c(x)e^x$. I thought integration by parts would help but that also depends on what $c(x)$ is. [image]

Comment: Have you got an answer to this now?

Comment: @md2perpe, yes, I'll be typing it up when I have time

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to observe that if $\phi \in \mathcal D$ then so is $e^{-x} \phi$.

Then by definition, $cf = 0$ implies $f(c \psi)=0$ for every $\psi \in \mathcal D$, and in particular, if we take any test function $\phi\in \mathcal D$, $e^{-x} \phi \in \mathcal D$ so that
$$
(cf)(e^{-x}\phi) = 0 = f\big(c (e^{-x}\phi)\big) = f(\phi)
$$
so $f(\phi)=0$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal D$.  Therefore $f = 0$.

Comment: That's one of the solutions; the trivial one in fact. There's apparently more!

Comment: Well I thought I have shown that $f=0$ is the only solution. Perhaps I’ve not understood the question. Are you asking for $f$ such that $e^x f=0$?  Or should that be $e^x f’=0$?

Comment: @user926034. What makes you think that there are more solutions to $e^x f = 0$?

Comment: @WADon no, the question is written correctly.

Comment: @md2perpe other than the wording of the question insinuating a lack of uniqueness, the lecturer.

Comment: Well, for the question as written I find the only possible solution is $f=0$ as I believe demonstrated by the given answer.

Comment: @user926034. Did the lecturer say that this particular case has more than one solution? My guess is that he said that a distributional equation can have other solutions than the classical ones, like $xf=x^2$ not only has $f=x$ but $f=x+C\delta$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: @md2perpe Unfortunately your guess would be incorrect. It was specifically about this question and the "hint" was that $f=0$ is trivial and we need to find the nontrivial solution(s).

Comment: @user926034. Then either the lecturer is wrong or your description of the exercise is wrong. An equation $cf=0$ can only have nontrivial solutions if there are points $x$ where $c(x)=0.$ That's not the case for $c(x)=e^x.$

Comment: @md2perpe Well I've copied the exercise exactly, and even added extra information from the book. I've also asked him and he says there's definitely an answer that will be provided next week. Until then, I'll assume again that you've guessed incorrectly. 
There is a third option which is that neither you nor I can do the question.
Further, I'm not sure if your response takes into account that we mean $0$ in the sense of distributions which is not necessarily $0$.

Comment: @user926034. I hope that you share the answer here. I'm really curious about it. Of course I understand that we mean $0$ in the sense of distributions: $u=0$ iff $\langle u, \phi \rangle = 0$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c.$

Comment: @user926034.  Me too.  I suspect if you read the answer above you could identify where the misunderstanding lies.